# Add a checkbox option to a PHP/MySQL form

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following form

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title pull-left"><img src="http://www.isfin.ro/images/institutul_de_studii_financiare_ISF.png" width="145px" height="80px" /></div>
        <div class="title pull-right"><h1>Actualizare newsletter</h1></div>
     </div>
    <hr class="featurette-divider"></hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        GDPR text goes here
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Adresa Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
        <input id="nume" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nume">
    </div>
    <p>Want to remain subscribed?</p>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="no">No
    </label>
    <br><br>
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-primary">Trimite</button>
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var em = $("#email").val();
var sub = $("#nume").val();
var com = $("#comments").val();
var dataString = 'em1='+ em + '&sub1='+ sub + '&com1='+ com;
if(em==''||sub==''||com=='')
{
$("#display").html("<div class='alert alert-warning'>Please Fill All Fields.</div>");
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "processor.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
$("#display").html(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is the content of processor.php

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['em1']);
$emailclean = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$sub=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sub1']);
$subclean = filter_var($sub, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
//insert into database
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO contact(`email`, `nume`)VALUES('$emailclean','$subclean')");
//send message back to AJAX
echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Preferintele au fost actualizate.</div>';
$con->close();
?>
```

How can I insert the content of the radio buttons Yes / No into a database field?
My database have the following structure id, email, nume, subscription_status, i need to insert the value from radio buttons into subscription_status (Yes or No value).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of selected checkbox:

`var data = document.querySelector('input[name="optradio"]:checked').value;`

Now add this value to your data string which you are sending via ajax:

`var dataString = 'em1='+ em + '&sub1='+ sub + '&com1='+ com + '&radio=' + data;`

And get the value on PHP/server side:

`$radio_value = $_POST['radio'];`